# How to get the ACTUAL version number for Windows 10 from command line? (NOT build number!)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

How do I get the version number for Windows 10 [`1903`], instead of the build number [`10.0.18362.592`], via command line?

Comment: 1903 is built number itself, the lates version number of windows <19 for sure

Comment: The big problem with this seems to be the inconsistency with the naming of the build numbers and the version numbers. What some refer to as the build number other's refer to as the version number and vice-versa

Comment: @SpacePhoenix that seems to be a matter of perspective.  When you navigate to Start > Run and enter *winver*, it very clearly shows you the **Version** as well as the **OS Build** number.  As a result, the "big problem" really seems to be customer education.

Comment: There are _two_ commands, see the difference: `ver` vs. `winver`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the build / version of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/963910/how-to-find-the-build-version-of-windows-10)

Comment: @Run5k if you use *ver* it shows the build number as the version number

Comment: Note that `10.0.18362.592` actually _is_ the version you are running - `1903` is a marketing name. (Yes, I understand why you want to see the latter, not the former)

Answer (score 51):

> How do I get the version, such as `1903`, instead of the "build number"?

The following PowerShell command will provide the information you are seeking: 
 <sup>(Source: [How to get Windows version from the command prompt or PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778858/how-to-get-windows-version-from-command-prompt-or-from-powershell))</sup>

- ```powershell
  (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').ReleaseId
  ```
- Registry query from the command prompt:

  ```powershell
  Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" | findstr ReleaseId
  ```

> I have no words for this. I've been spending a ridiculous amount of time searching and searching and searching a million times, and every single webpage on the Internet keeps telling me about the worthless `ver` command or `wmic blabla`, which does not give you the version number.

I must point out the version of Windows you are using is actually the Build version (i.e. `18363`), instead of ReleaseID (i.e. `1909`)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1330269/how-to-get-os-version-through-powershell-with-wmi)

- You would use `[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version` to tell the difference between Windows 7 Service Pack 1 and Windows 7 RTM[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1693093/get-the-windows-10-code-name-e-g-21h2-via-cli-even-on-a-fresh-installation)

Answer (score 27):

```powershell
Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 20):

#### Powershell

```
Get-ComputerInfo -Property "WindowsVersion"
```

[image: Powershell Get-ComputerInfo output]

<sup>**Picture 1:** Above the whole output of the `Get-ComputerInfo` powershell invocation,  without options.</sup>

#### Some words more

The Microsoft Windows operating system was first labelled with standard version numbers from 1 to 3.11 (read the full chapter <sup>[[w](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Microsoft_Windows)]</sup>)... then after some leaps and many years, in windows 10 the subsequent OS updates only incremented the build number and update build revision (UBR) number (see below).

In windows 10 the version number requested by the OP is based on the date of the most recent large build release and uses a YYMM format <sup>[[2](https://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/)]</sup>. This version number is the one we can find e.g. via  *Settings* panel, then  `System > About` and we can read the Version (**Shortcut** <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and gives a prompter information about the OS update state.

> **Version**<sup>[[2](https://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/)]</sup> The version number gives you the best information on what version of Windows 10 you’re running. **The number is based on the date of the most recent large build release and uses a YYMM format.** For example, in the screenshot above, the “1607” version tells us that the version we’re running is from the 7th month (July) of 2016.

BTW from the command prompt you can directly ask to open `winver` and read the version number from the second line <sup>[[3](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-check-your-computer-full-specifications-windows-10#check-specs-using-powershell)]</sup>...

```
winver
```

#### `systeminfo`

In `systeminfo` it is available the OS version (the one with the built number, e.g 10.0.18362) that you may compare with a list similar to the above one, and the Original Install Date. I don't know if for each major upgrade the Original Install Date value is updated (Remember that YYMM gives that number). At least as minimum you can reconstruct the first installed version on your machine.

#### A List <sup>[[4](https://www.lifewire.com/windows-version-numbers-2625171),[R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Rings)]</sup>

```
Windows 10 (1903)       10.0.18362
Windows 10 (1809)       10.0.17763
Windows 10 (1803)       10.0.17134
Windows 10 (1709)       10.0.16299
Windows 10 (1703)       10.0.15063
Windows 10 (1607)       10.0.14393
Windows 10 (1511)       10.0.10586
Windows 10              10.0.10240  

Windows 8.1 (Update 1)  6.3.9600
Windows 8.1             6.3.9200
Windows 8               6.2.9200

Windows 7 SP1           6.1.7601
Windows 7               6.1.7600

Windows Vista SP2       6.0.6002
Windows Vista SP1       6.0.6001
Windows Vista           6.0.6000

Windows XP2             5.1.26003
```

You can read an updated version of the list on wikipedia page <sup>[[R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Rings)]</sup>.

Comment: If you're wanting just the number (say for displaying on a GUI) you can use `(Get-ComputerInfo).WindowsVersion` in PowerShell instead of using the `property` tag. Then you don't get the table format, either. But thanks, this is the solution I was looking for a couple weeks ago!

Comment: @KGlasier or just `Get-ComputerInfo WindowsVersion`

Answer (score 10):

Some options in PowerShell:

- ```powershell
  (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').ReleaseId
  ```

  or

  ```powershell
  (Get-ComputerInfo).WindowsVersion
  ```
- With alias:

  ```powershell
  (gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').ReleaseId
  ```

  or

  ```powershell
  (gin).WindowsVersion
  ```
- Save output in clipboard (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

  ```powershell
  (gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').ReleaseId | clip
  ```

  or

  ```powershell
  (gin).WindowsVersion | clip
  ```

---

- Actual Version output only: (returns `1903`)

  ```powershell
  for /f tokens^=^3 %i in ('Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId')do
    echo/%i|clip
  ```
- For add/set var in command line and send to output and clipboard (**<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>**)

  ```powershell
  for /f tokens^=^3 %i in ('Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId')do
    echo/%i && set "_bildernumber=%i"
    echo %_bildernumber%|clip
  ```
- For add/set var in cmd/bat file and send output to clipboard (**<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>**)

  ```powershell
  @echo off

  for /f tokens^=^3 %%i in ('Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId')do
    echo/%%i && set "_bildernumber=%%i"
    echo %_bildernumber%|clip
  ```

  or

  ```powershell
  @echo off

  for /f tokens^=^3 %%i in ('Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId')do
    echo/%%i && set "_bildernumber=%%i"
    echo %_bildernumber%|clip
  ```

Answer (score 5):

You could try `winver`, which provides a pop-up window showing Version, Build and/or Service Pack numbers.

Comment: This works perfectly.

Comment: It is not clear by the current revision of the question but this is not actually want the author wanted.  They wanted an output within the command and/or PowerShell prompt.  There have been more than 3 answers deleted due this fact.  While this detail was removed from the body for several reasons, the title of this question, makes the author's specific requirements clear.

Answer (score 1):

#### Cygwin:

```powershell
Reg Query 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' |grep ReleaseId |sed -E 's/.* ([^ ]+)/\1/'
```

- `reg query` is similar to other answers
- `grep ReleaseId` finds the line with the Release ID
- By using the `sed -E 's/.* ([^ ]+)/\1/'` POSIX regular expression syntax, `-E` matches any characters followed by a space, then captures a group of one or more non-space characters. This will get the last field on the line *(without `-E` it would require backslash escaping the parentheses and the plus sign)* and substitute that captured group of non-space characters, which is the value we're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've done lots of searching and came along this post, for what you're looking for this is the simplest answer
`Get-ComputerInfo | select windowsversion`