# Windows 10 Pro doesn't show version of Windows, can this be fixed?

Tags: windows-10-pro

I use a computer at work which has Windows 10 Pro installed but when I look to see its version, it doesn't show it, it just shows Edition and that's 64 bit. I need to see its version since a paid software I want to install there requires a certain version on to work.

Is this a bug? Can which version of Windows 10 Pro be seen in any installation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the ACTUAL version number for Windows 10 from command line? (NOT build number!)](https://superuser.com/questions/1519110/how-to-get-the-actual-version-number-for-windows-10-from-command-line-not-buil)

Comment: It's related but not a dupe. OP here doesn't ask for a command line solution, just 'a solution'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way is

- Click Start
- Type `winver`
- Hit Enter.

[image]

This works at least back to Windows 7, if not earlier [nothing to test that on]

Comment: I think this method dates back to DOS-based versions of Windows (except pre-Vista you had to type it into Run window, obviously).

Answer (score 5):

Go to Start, System, then About (scroll down to the bottom of the left side list to see About) and that will tell you the Version (say 1909) and the Build  (18363.393).

Unless you have a Long Term Service version (Companies can do this), Windows 10 will inevitably update, so you need to contact the vendor of the paid software to let them know Windows 10 changes feature versions every 6 to 9 months.

[image]

Comment: Maybe my Windows (1909) is set up differently from yours, but I had to right-click on Start to get to System.

Comment: I can do it either way. The main point is to get to the Windows Settings main screen so you can see System