# Windows Version missing?

Tags: windows, windows-10-v2004

I'm sure my laptop is running Windows 10 2004 but this info is missing from all places I know it should be displayed. Anyone knows why or how to get it back?

It happened before and now that I have just reset Windows, it is there again.

Winver

[image: WinVer]

About

[image]

Comment: This cannot be solved by a DISM or SFC scan.  Performing a repair install is an uncessary and overkill solution to a simple problem.  [The version is handled by a registry key.](https://superuser.com/questions/1519110/how-to-get-the-actual-version-number-for-windows-10-from-command-line-not-buil/1519122#1519122).  If you will provide the necessary information from you registry I will provide a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks for that @Ramhound. I followed that link, which points me to a reg key that is already correct. I was really hoping that would be right answer, but again it's a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

**Start by trying DISM and SFC.**

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run in order:

1. dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth
2. SFC /SCANNOW

Restart when done and test WinVer again.

If the DISM repair does not fix the issue, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

**Windows 10 Repair Install**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

The test your Versioning again.

Comment: Do a Windows 10 Repair Install - that is the next step. I will augment my post

Comment: Well, I just did it a few days ago. This "problem" was there already even before this recent repair. Once the repair was done, the version number showed up but after some regular software setup it is gone again. So, I don't think that would be the right way to solve it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Perhaps at this point back up your system and do a fresh install of Windows.  Since the problem is resolved and then resurfaces, install Windows, check, and install software carefully.

Comment: seems like overkill solution to me. I`ll try to find another path that implies minor prejudice. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Since nothing else worked, that is probably your only solution. Something has gone wrong that cannot be fixed otherwise. I have seen this before.