# How to get the windows version with command line?

Tags: command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

If I'm in `CMD` I can use `winver`

[image]

I can see my OS version is `20H2` now. But this is GUI result, I want to use command line to make it. If I use

```
ver
```

> Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.19042.868]

If I'm in powershell, I can use

```
Get-ComputerInfo WindowsVersion
```

> ```
> WindowsVersion
> -------------- 
> 2009
> ```

So how to get the version like **"20H2"** in command line(powershell or cmd)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value can be found under registry key
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
inside the value named `DisplayVersion`.

The following PowerShell command will get it:

```
(Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue('DisplayVersion')
```

Comment: You might want to point out that DisplayVersion does appear to have existed before 20H2.  On my 1909 system it returns nothing[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1519110/how-to-get-the-actual-version-number-for-windows-10-from-command-line-not-buil)

Comment: @Ramhound: Strange. But anyway, `DisplayVersion` was the only value in my registry that contained the string `20H2`, so without it one needs manually to map the numeric value of `ReleaseId` to a name.

Comment: Microsoft changed from using `Version 2004` to `Version 20H2` with the release of 20H2.  It appears that `ReleaseId` is still the YYMM date format.

Comment: A little dirty but work, thanks :)